# Yahoo Finance API. Display all companies

Tags: api, yahoo, finance

How to get the list of all available companies in Yahoo Finance API?

I didn't find anything anywhere regarding this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Companies lists in CSV format can be found here:

http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx